# How to remove value from comma separated string using update query?

Tags: mysql

```
Recruiter list,Employer List,Latest Jobs,Intrested Recruiter,Recruiter Resume,Shortlisted Hr Resume

UPDATE assign SET menu=REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', menu, ','), 'Shortlisted Hr Resume', ''), ',,', ',') WHERE hr_id='hr2911025540'
```

In this case, I have a string `Recruiter List, Shortlisted Hr Resume, Add Hr`. Now I want to remove only `Shortlisted Hr Resume` but this query replace value from both ending and output look like `,Employer List,Latest Jobs,Intrested Recruiter,Recruiter Resume,` So, How can I do this please help me ?

Comment: The best solution is to seperate and normalize these values. Having such a cumulated list of values always opens a ton of problems

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad on why you shouldn't use comma separated values in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE groups
SET
  description =
    TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', description, ','), ', Shortlisted Hr Resume,', ','))
  WHERE id='1'
```

You can also

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  description =
    TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(CONCAT(',',REPLACE(col, ',', ',,'), ','),',2,', ''), ',,', ',')
    )
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET('2', description)
```